# Unable to bring value from webservice to UI using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web service , i give two fields as input to the web-service and in return it gives me details of that user.Now my challenge is that I have to show this output on UI using (Angular JS+MVC).In UI i have two input field and on hitting "get"button I require a table to be populated with the user details from the web-service.I have created a controller added view. In the view I have coded the Html part and i m trying to write a script for controller to populate the table from webservice on ng-click event of button..but not getting output.

```
<html data-ng-app="RESTClientModule">  
<head>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Modules.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Services.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/Controllers.js"></script> *@ 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  

    @*OP COMING FROM THE WEBSERVICE TO BE DISPLAYED IN UI*@
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController">  
        <tr>  
            <td>  
                <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">  
                    <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">  
                        <th></th>  
                        <th>CensusNumber</th>  
                        <th>EmployeeOid</th>  

                    </tr>  
                    <tbody data-ng-repeat="ObjCensus in EeCensus">  
                        <tr>  
                            <td></td>  
                            <td><span>{{ObjCensus.CensusNr}}</span></td>  
                            <td><span>{{ObjCensus.EmployeeOid}}</span></td>             
                        </tr>  
                    </tbody>  


   </table>  

        </td>  
    </tr>  

    @*ui for ip on basis of which we will get op from webservice in our table *@

    <tr>  
        <td>  

                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">  
                    <tr>  
                        <td></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <span>ParticipantOid</span>  
                        </td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" id="ParticipantOid" data-ng-model="ParticipantOid" />  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                    <tr>  
                        <td></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <span>ProductAccountOid</span>  
                        </td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" id="ProductAccountOid" required data-ng-model="ProductAccountOid" />  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                  </table>

                 <input type="button" id="getCensus" value="Get it" data-ng-click="get(ParticipantOid,ProductAccountOid)" />  
         </body>    

    <script>
        //The below JavaScript defines Angular Module with the name RESTClientModule.This is the Bootstrapper for the application.
        var app;
        (function () {
            debugger;
            app = angular.module("RESTClientModule", []);
        })();

        ////The below JavaScript code defines Angular Controller on the Module which defines $scope to be bound with the UI. 

        app.controller("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController", function ($scope, CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService) {
            // debugger;
            var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.get(EeCensus.ParticipantOid, EeCensus.ProductAccountOid);
            promiseGet.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.EeCensus = pl.data
            },
                      function (errorPl) {
                          $log.error('failure loading Employee', errorPl);
                      });
        });

        ////The above JavaScript code define the Angular Service of name CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService in the Angular module. 
        ////    This makes use of $http to make call to the WCF REST service.
        app.service("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService", function ($http) {

            debugger;
            this.get = function (ParticipantOid, ProductAccountOid) {
                return $http.get("http://localhost:58556/CensusService.svc" + (ParticipantOid,ProductAccountOid));
            }
        });
    </script>                                 
</html>
```

Comment: `promiseGet.then(function (pl) {
                $scope.EeCensus = pl.data
                 console.log($scope.EeCensus);
            },`

Comment: check the output of above console.log in your then block .

Answer (score 0):

When click the button `get()` function is called, but there is no `get()` function in the controller.

```
<input type="button" id="getCensus" value="Get it" data-ng-click="get(ParticipantOid,ProductAccountOid)" />
```

You can add following code to `CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController` to solve the problem.

```
     app.controller("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTController", function ($scope, CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService) {

          $scope.get = function(ParticipantOid, ProductAccountOid){
          // here call service to get your data
          // debugger;
          CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.get(EeCensus.ParticipantOid, EeCensus.ProductAccountOid)then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.EeCensus = pl.data
                },
            function (errorPl) {
               $log.error('failure loading Employee', errorPl);
             });
            }

         });
```

Comment: Actually i m accessing a wcf service, not wcf rest.. do i need to follow anything different for the former????